# Forcing ReactJS to update render on functional components doesn't work without a second force

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks

I'm working on an application where I have an array of data obtained from server (Ajax) that is rendered on screen.

To select the position that I want to render (Array[0], Array[1], Array[2]), I have a component select that on select option (handle onChange), writes on localStorage the option. Then, on the render data code, I have as a position var this localStorage value.

Since ReactJS doesn't re-render the screen every frame, I have to indicate React that he has to re-render the screen in order to show a different data position.

To do this, I have a Hook:

```js
function useForceUpdate() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    return () => setValue((value) => ++value);
}
const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
```

The problem is, that if I call this hook on the handle of the select component, It doesn't update the render. But if you do a second change on the select (basically, you are calling the Hook again), it draws the last one option (So if at the first time you have selected the option of value=1.. And then you select the option of value=2, it draws the value=1).

I have added a button to call the function (button -> forceRe-Render), and it works. So, if you choose any option and click on the button, it shows the correct information.

PS: Checking the localStorage, it's working fine, so it's not a problem of localStorage.

Here is the codesandbox of a summary of it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-glitter-s830r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The main challenge you have is you aren't using React Hooks to your advantage to pass state between the components. I suggest you check out this article: https://medium.com/@renatognunes/react-hooks-passing-child-component-state-up-with-useref-de88401c2654

Comment: The problem is onInput is called before onChange. If you swap those props on your select it will work. But I think you have misunderstood what local storage is. I think its best if you learn how to pass state from parent to child.

Comment: @TonyDrummond First of all, thanks! Very interesting article. In this particular case, I'm working with localStorage because is a very specific situation. 95% of the user will never change it.. And the ones that will use it.. It will be occasionally. Also, would be interested to have the value between sessions.

Comment: @ArunaHerath Oh! I was too focused that the problem was more complex.. That I didn't realize about the execution order. Thanks!! PS: In this specific case, I think it's interesting to work with localStorage because most of the users will never use it.. And the ones that will do, should be persistent between sessions. Imagine this select like "User selection menú" inside an account (for example gmail, where you can choose between two mails). In other cases, I agree that using "useRef", "useContext" or similar would be better.

Comment: Why can't you set local storage to your state variable while also passing state up to the parent? You can do both, so long as you're operating off of one state variable.

Comment: I guess you are right here. I can store the value on localStorage to be able to have a persistent value during sessions.. And then, passing the state in order to do a better use of hooks.